# C++ FLT_MIN returns a positive?

Tags: c#, c++

I've narrowed down the problem hugely and it seems that FLT_MIN returns a positive number in C++ of around 1.1. In C# float.MinValue is -3.4. Both numbers have A LOT of decimal places, but why the difference between the two?

I don't quite understand these values. I thought they would return a number very very close to 0 but slightly on the positive side. Either that or the largest (so to speak) negative number it is possible to store. These don't do either.

**Edit** sorry for the huge question change, but this is the actual problem and this is much more helpful to others.

**EDIT** the inverse C++ max is the same as the min value in C#

Comment: The code samples here are too large, please make them smaller (ie, make a test case).

Comment: Step through them both in a debugger and see where their behaviour deviates. That's the bug.

Comment: I just did this, and the first thing I notice that differs is dirfrac.z is not the same in each. in C# it's approx -3.4 and in C++ it's approx 1.1. Not sure why though.

Comment: @EricLippert and t5 and t6 in the C# version are infinity and -infinity respectively. In C++ they are -1.4105933e-038 and 3.2913841e-038

Comment: as a result the min and max functions return the opposite of what they should in the C++ one. This results in tmax having the wrong result in the current test case. in C++ tmax is not greater than tmin and is returning -1 (tmax should be around 38 but is instead 3.4 etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FLT_MIN` is defined in C99 and referred to by C++0x as the "minimum normalized positive floating-point number". I wonder how you get `1.1`.

If you want to get the smallest finite number re presentable in a type, you can use `std::numeric_limits<>::lowest()` defined in `<limits>`. For example, `std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest()` would give you the smallest number in `float`, which is (the most) negative.

Comment: by typing FLT_MIN. It's actually 1.175494351e-38F

Comment: You missed the most important part of that number: `e-38`. Move the decimal point left 38 digits. So it's more like 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000001175494351. Is that small enough for you?

Comment: Yes it is! you're right I was misunderstanding. also your last sentence made me genuinely laugh out loud!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `min` and `max` are both 3D vectors as well as functions (or macros). In the C# version you have `min` and `max` for the vectors, and `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` for the function.

My guess is that your vector class has an operator() with two args so that you don't get compilation errors, but this is not the same as the usual min(..)/max(..) function.

Comment: the c++ vector class? min and max simply return the smaller or larger of two values.

Comment: You have a variable `D3DXVECTOR3 min`

Comment: the way you use them differentiates them. variables don't accept parameters.

Comment: If the class has an `operator()` it will *look as if* the variable accepts parameters. This is my guess to the reason that your code compiles.